# Why is top: 0 for absolute component not working in react native?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native

I have a SearchBar component that I need to appear over the ScrollView component towards the top of the screen (under the header).  Currently, it is not snapping to the top even though I have top: 0 set on it.  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Here is the render:

```
render() {
    const {isLoading, products} = this.props.products;

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Loader isVisible={true}/>;
    }

    return (<View style={styles.wrapper}>
        <Header/>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
            <ProductsContainer data={{productsList: { results: products }}}/>
        </ScrollView>
        <SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>
        <Footer/>
    </View>);
}
```

Here are the styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    wrapper: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        position: 'relative'
    },
    searchBar: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 100000,
        top: 0
    },
    scrollView: {
        position: 'relative',
        zIndex: 0
    }
});
```

Here is how it currently looks in my app:

[image]

Comment: Check the element wrapper if really wraps everything, I mean if it starts from top. That might be the referenced element for searchBar and top might be different than you expect.

Comment: can you create a fiddle showing your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing proper dimensions and zIndex from your `searchBar` style declaration. For instance this would render as expected:

```
...
searchBar: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  height: 44,
  zIndex: 2,
},
...
```

Comment: I replaced my searchBar styles exactly with yours but it still looks the same.  Still will not go to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set a width (width:'100%') and to put your SearchBar outside of your main view.

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
                <SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>
                <View style={styles.wrapper}>
                ...
```

- Edit:
  Are you using a virtual device? i noticed mine doesn't like absolute positionning, you could try to run your code on a real device.